# Must inversion commute?

Tags: functions

Is there a function $f$ s.t. $f^{-1}(f(x))\neq f(f^{-1}(x))$?

Comment: Please clarify what your definition of $f^{-1}$ is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The interpretation for $f^{-1}(f(x))=x$ is that $x$ is in the domain of $f$. However that of $f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ is that $x$ is in the domain of $f^{-1}$ or the range of $f$. Thus if $x$ is both in the domain and the range of $f$,  then $f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$. Otherwise $f^{-1}(f(x))=f(f^{-1}(x))=x$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

No, because the definition of inverse functions implies that $(f^{-1})^{-1}=f$, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Symmetry).